# Browser page refresh default time?

Tags: internet-explorer, refresh-rate

What is the default time for Internet explorer to refresh the page automatically ?

is there any summarized data  for this info ?

I can't find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page auto-refresh depends on how the page is coded, not the browser